# PHP download resume support issue

Tags: php, download

When i am downloading file from server it give NO resume support.

Here is the code:

```
if ($zc['mm'] && $zc['mm_down'] && preg_match('/\.('.$zc['mm_ext'].')$/i', $path, $exts)) {
    $file = $zc['mp3_dir'].'/'.$path;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        if ($zc['stream_int']) {
            $ext = strtolower($exts[1]);
            zina_set_header('Content-Type: '.$zc['mm_types'][$ext]['mime']);
            $disposition = (isset($zc['mm_types'][$ext]['disposition'])) ? $zc['mm_types'][$ext]['disposition'] : 'attachment';
            zina_set_header('Content-Disposition: '.$disposition.'; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
            zina_set_header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
            zina_set_header('Cache-control: public'); #IE seems to need this.
            zina_set_header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n"); 
            zina_set_header('Content-Type: $contentType');
            zina_send_file($file);
        }
        else {
            zina_goto($path,NULL,NULL,TRUE,TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Can Anyone help me how to make this code Resume Supportable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really think an all-uppercase title is appropriate?! Besides that, you really need to indent your code...

Comment: You need to handle the Range header. You wont get much help here unless you show that you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty complex to add resume support on your own - the `Range` header you'd need to check supports not only simple ranges but rather complex ones, too.

The only really easy and clean solution is using something like the `X-Sendfile` header (native support in Lighttpd, [module](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) available for Apache) which tells your web server to send a certain file to the user. Resuming, parallel downloads etc. will work fine in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am hosting this site in IIS. IIS is providing resume support on other static sites but not on this site. Need Help!